# Phonegap Cross-domain http Request not working on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cross-domain

I have index.html on my local machine in which

```
var layer = Tangram.leafletLayer({          
             scene: 'http://xx.xx.x.xx:8080/myApp/styles/scene_building.yaml',     
            });
```

and try to access the file from remote server and its giving me this error

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

in config.xml.
I have added this
access origin="*" 
I am trying to run on my device.

Comment: Are you running this code in an emulator? If so, please add that to your post. And respond here so I kno w you made the change.

Comment: Please add that to your post.